# Disable drag on create event

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to disable the dragging function when a user create a event.
My events should have a fixed duration of 30 min.

I'm using version 2.0.3 of fullcalendar.

I've tried using, but that do not help.

```
eventDurationEditable : false,
```

Any ideas as how to prevent dragging on create?

/Birger

Comment: try eventStartEditable: false

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it don't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Event start editable to false.

```
eventStartEditable:false,
```

More info: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/eventStartEditable